Error while trying to open a new workspace in pycharm
I'm having this error while trying to open a new workspace can someone help me?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in run_code
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz_main.py", line 163, in 
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz_main.py", line 159, in run
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv_main_.py", line 18, in run
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\run_init_.py", line 33, in cli_run
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\run\session.py", line 45, in run
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\run\session.py", line 58, in _seed
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 71, in run
RuntimeError: failed to build image setuptools because:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 57, in _install
installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 37, in install
self._sync(filename, into)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\copy.py", line 13, in _sync
copy(src, dst)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\util\path_sync.py", line 41, in copy
method(str(src), str(dest))
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.24.5.pyz\virtualenv\util\path_sync.py", line 52, in copytree
shutil.copy(src_f, dest_f)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\shutil.py", line 431, in copy
copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\shutil.py", line 256, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\HARUN BERKE �ZT�RK\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Local\pypa\virtualenv\wheel\3.11\image\1\CopyPipInstall\setuptools-68.2.0-py3-none-any\setuptools\config\_validate_pyproject\fastjsonschema_exceptions.py'
.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
